# Kivy App on android crush, and say permission denied in logcat

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm creating an app using python and kivy, I request a json arquive by url, but when I built it with buildozer and open it in with mobile of Android 7, it crushed, and in logcat log displayed "I python  :  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 13] Permission denied",it works if I took off the url request.

```
    [app]

# (str) Title of your application
#[1]
title = Estacionamento_ip

# (str) Package name
#[2]
package.name = estacionamento_ip

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
#[3]
version = 0.1.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy, android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =


# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
#[4]
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
#[5]
fullscreen = 0

#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
[6]
android.permissions = INTERNET, NETWORK

# (int) Android API to use
#[7]
android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#[8]
android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#[9]
android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#[10]
android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#[11]
android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in  tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer:   ()"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
#[12]
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

buildozer.spec

```
def update(self, *args):
        url = "http://192.168.100.101"#ip do ethernet shield
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data =json.loads(response.read())
        vaga_1 = int(data["arduino"][0]["situacao"])
        vaga_2 = int(data["arduino"][1]["situacao"])
        #vaga_1=1
        #vaga_2=0
        if vaga_1 == 1:
            self.ids['vaga01'].background_color = ocupado
        if vaga_1 == 0:
            self.ids['vaga01'].background_color = livre
```

main.py, if I comment the url request part the app don't crush

```
04-01 20:51:21.455  7276  7307 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
04-01 20:51:21.490  7276  7307 I python  : [INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
04-01 20:51:21.491  7276  7307 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 20:51:21.491  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 41, in <module>
04-01 20:51:21.492  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
04-01 20:51:21.493  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
04-01 20:51:21.494  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
04-01 20:51:21.495  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 290, in _mainloop
04-01 20:51:21.495  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in idle
04-01 20:51:21.496  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 515, in tick
04-01 20:51:21.497  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 647, in _process_events
04-01 20:51:21.498  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 406, in tick
04-01 20:51:21.499  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 20, in update
04-01 20:51:21.499  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
04-01 20:51:21.500  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
04-01 20:51:21.501  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 342, in open_http
04-01 20:51:21.502  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
04-01 20:51:21.503  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
04-01 20:51:21.503  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
04-01 20:51:21.504  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 754, in connect
04-01 20:51:21.505  7276  7307 I python  :    File "/media/alec/Data/TG/re/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
04-01 20:51:21.506  7276  7307 I python  :  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 13] Permission denied
04-01 20:51:21.581  7276  7307 I python  : Python for android ended.
04-01 20:51:21.582  7276  7307 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
```

after "04-01 20:51:21.455  7276  7307 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available" ṕart is the difference that appear if i use the urlrequest.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I dont know if this makes any difference, but should `[6]` be commented out, right above android.permissions?

Comment: It work, thank you